# Атрибут в динамическом компоненте Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-cli

Создаю компонент

```
let ComponentClass = Vue.extend(AppWin) 
let instance = new ComponentClass()
instance.$mount()
this.$refs.container.appendChild(instance.$el)
```

Как туда добавить слушатель `emit`

В статичном компоненте так `<AppWin @close="appClose"/>`

А в динамичном?

Answer (score 1):

```
instance.$on('close', function () {
  /* ... */
});
```

Есть в документации API: https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-on